# 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'group'**

The code is here

```
class TripView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
lookup_field = 'id'
lookup_url_kwarg = 'trip_id'
serializer_class = NestedTripSerializer
permissions_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.user
    if user.group == 'driver':
        return Trip.objects.filter(
            Q(status=Trip.REQUESTED) | Q(driver=user)
        )
    if user.group == 'rider':
        return Trip.objects.filter(rider=user)
    return Trip.objects.none()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have typo, it must `permission_classes`, so:

```
permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
```

not `permissions_classes`